# Increase Java heapsize in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, memory, windows-7, heap-memory

I'm not sure if I did it right. I checked other the other answers at SO and I want to set up 512mb for heapsize. That's why I set up `-Xms512m` in the Control Panel->...->Java Runtime Enviroment Settings.
It looks fine, Apply and OK clicked.

However, to check the current changes (applied 512mb), I use `javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize"` in the command line and it shows only 129349696, not 512mb.

What am I doing wrong?

Restarting the system didn't help.

Comment: The common way to do it is to provide a command line argument, javaw -Xms512m -Xmx1024m will set a minimum heap of 512m and a maximum heap of 1gb. That way you have 100% certainty rather than having to depend on user-controlled system settings (and you can automate that by creating a shell script, or by using something like ANT/Maven). I don't really know what the settings in the control panel do, but my best guess is that they actually control the settings of the browser sandbox environment and not the regular Java runtime environment you manually start with java/javaw.